# How to use select statement within select statements if condition

Tags: mysql, subquery

**What I am trying to do:**

I want to get the name of the product with it's id from orders table , but in my case I have stored products in 3 different tables.
i.e dish,drinks,others.

**Problem:**

So the problem is in orders table i have put a type(what kind of product it is) like "dirnks,dish,others".So how can i get the name of the product when product can be in any tables(dish,drinks,others)

**What i want:**

I don't whether it's possible or not but if anyone can tell what below query is there,how can i use select statement in IF statment

```
    SELECT product_id,type,quantity ,
     ( IF(type='Drinks)
       THEN
       (SELECT drink_name FROM drinks WHERE drink_id=product_id) 
       ELSE IF (type='Dish)
       THEN
       (SELECT dish_name FROM dish WHERE dish_id=product_id) 
    )  
      as drink_name
    FROM order_product

   WHERE shop_id='JSMMSK730'
```

Is this thing possible or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `UNION`, and add a new column to the subquery that indicates which table the rows came from. Then you can use this in the `JOIN` condition.

```
SELECT product_id, o.type, quantity, name FROM 
order_product o JOIN
(
    SELECT "dish" type, dish_id id, drink_name name from dish
    UNION
    SELECT "drinks" type, drink_id id, drink_name name from drinks
    UNION
    SELECT "others" type, other_id id, other_name name from others
) p
ON p.id = o.product_id and p.type = o.type
WHERE shop_id = 'JSMMSK730'
```

Comment: first of all thank you very much, it almost works but i am getting a small problem here and i.e on the p.type = o.type here the mysql says #1267 - Illegal mix of collations error , how do i make "dish" as latin1_swedish_ci in your query

Answer (score 0):

Try below Syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT product_id, product_name from dish
    UNION
    SELECT product_id, product_name from drinks
    UNION
    SELECT product_id, product_name from others) as product, order
)
WHERE product.product_id = order.order_id
```